# How to query for top 10 directories based on size?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am very new to Django and I'm creating a simple app to track disk usage and show changes over time, etc.:

```
class Directory(models.Model):
  path = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Directory_Size(models.Model):
  drivedir = models.ForeignKey(Directory, related_name = 'sizes')
  measure_date = models.DateTimeField()
  size = models.IntegerField()
```

`Directory_Sizes` stores the size of the directory and the time it was recorded. There will be many of these for each Directory.

How do I select the current size of the directory? I need the newest `Directory_Size` for each `Directory`.

How would I select the top 10 directories based on size, this would be a simple order by size and then limit to 10, can this be done by chaining the `order_by` and limit onto the top of the query above?

Should I change the models to make this type of thing easier?

I'm assuming this is simple and I don't know how because of my lack of Django knowledge.

Comment: What @Marcin said, the best way for you to learn is to just try stuff. Just keep trying stuff and then, when you don't understand the results, come and ask. I could tell you how to do the above, and it sounds like you have the right general idea, so just execute it. That's my recommendation. There's nothing special about Django if you know your Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Now my question is how do I select the current size of the directory. I need the newest Directory_Size for each directory.

```
d = Directory.objects.get( ...
d_size = d.sirectory_size_set.order_by( '-measure_date')[0].size
```

2)  select the top 10 directories based on size: I think you need a custom [raw query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/).

```
for p in Directory.objects.raw(
    'SELECT *, (select ...) as s FROM myapp_directory order by s LIMIT 10'
)
```

Where `(select ...)` is a subquery to get actual size, also you can do a join ...

Answer (score 2):

This isn't related to your questions, but Django naming standards would tell you to name the model `DirectorySize`, not `Directory_Size`. You use *either* CamelCase or lowercase with underscores, not both (it's an xor). In general, classes (and therefore, models) are named using CamelCase. Function definitions and variables are lowercase with underscores.

source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/

Answer (score 0):

`sizes` will return a manager on which you can perform filtering operations. So this:

```
last_10_sizes = the_directory.sizes.order_by('-measure_date')[:10]
```

will return the latest 10 sizes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Directory_Size.objects.all().order_by('-size')[:10]
```

However that is pretty crude and all objects.

You can filter on a mesure date as well and give a range, something like

```
 import datetime
 start_date = datetime.datetime(<values_here>)
 end_date = datetime.datetime(<values_here>) 
    Directory_Size.objects.filter(measure_date__gte=start_date, measure_date__lte=end_date).order_by('-size')[:10]
```

do you need historical data, why not update the same dir and make it modified date with a default of of datetime.datetime.utc_now()?